# Python - Hide a worksheet

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am following the code to hide a worksheet using xlsxwriter. Anyone knows why this is failing?

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hide_sheet.html

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('Sheet1')
worksheet.hide()
workbook.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hide'
```

The Excel has two worksheets: "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"

Comment: XlsxWriter cannot read an existing file. It can only create new files.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the `column` of your `worksheet` by `worksheet.set_column()`

> Here is the correct code

```py
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('Sheet1')
worksheet.set_column('A:A',30)
worksheet.hide()
workbook.close()
```